# Module not found while i import the 'loadash' module from yarn

Tags: javascript

I install node, npm and yarn.
const _ = require('loadash');
const people = require('./people');

console.log(people);

console.log(_.last(people));

When i run this code, i find this error. [problem details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfaj9.jpg)

I just run this code and expecting ta last value of the array.

Comment: You mean `'lodash'`?

Comment: please edit your question, format the code that is in it, and include the error message in the question, instead of providing an image.

Answer (score 0):

use **lodash** not **loadash**

> npm i lodash

> const _ = require('lodash')